# How do we approximate sum of random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation, random-variables

Suppose we have independent, identically distributed random variables $X_n \notin L^1$.

I would like to approximate, in some way, the distribution of their sum $\sum X_n$
.The problem is that these variables are not in $L^1$! Otherwise the central limit theorem may have helped.

Do you guys have any ideas or resources to look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the distribution of each variable, try computing the characteristic function of the partial sums $S_n=\sum_{i=k}^n X_k$, and testing out various normalizations $S_n/c_n$.

For any random variable $Y$, integrable or not, the characteristic function (CF) of $Y$ is
$$\varphi_Y(t):=E\exp(itY)\;.$$
If $S_n$ is the sum of iid variables $X_1+\cdots+X_n$, the CF of $S_n/c_n$ factors into a product of $n$ terms:
$$\varphi_{S_n/c_n}(t)=E\exp(it\sum_{k=1}^n X_k/c_n)=\prod_{k=1}^nE\exp(itX_k/c_n)=[\varphi_X(t/c_n)]^n\;.$$
With luck the CF of the normalized sum will converge to a non-trivial limit (which with luck you'll recognize as the distribution of some random variable $Z$). This implies that you can approximate the distribution of $S_n/c_n$ as $Z$ when $n$ is sufficiently large.

For example, the CF approach can be used to show that the average of $n$ iid Cauchy random variables has the same Cauchy distribution as a single variable.

Comment: thanks! I'll try this approach. At the moment I'm stuck trying to compute the CF.. I've made a question for this here, if you want to take a look :) (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257702/finding-value-of-exponential-sum)

Comment: Your distribution looks very intractable, unfortunately. I should remark that for a distribution like yours, you'll need to recenter the partial sums to have any hope of a limiting distribution, i.e. you need to consider $(S_n-a_n)/c_n$