# Finding value of exponential sum

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, probability-theory, summation, fourier-analysis

I'd like to find the value of the following sum

$$S(u) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{iu2^n}}{2^{n+1}}$$
for $u \in \mathbb R$, but I can't seem to do it.

**Unfruitful work**

Writing $$S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{(iu2^n)^p}{2^{n+1}p!}$$
is proven useless because I can't exchange the order of summation.

Writing $$S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos(u2^n)}{2^{n+1}} + i \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin(u2^n)}{2^{n+1}}$$

seems also useless. Maybe it would be useful to find a fourier series that has those coefficients, but I have no idea on how to do that and anyhow since $u \in \mathbb R$ is not limited I don't think it can be done.

Someone has some ideas?

**P.S.**

If $X$ is a random variable with distribution $P(X=2^k) = \frac 1{2^{k+1}}$, then $S(u)$ is its charachteristic function. That is why I'm interested in finding it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a "closed form" solution in terms of standard functions.  If you write $S(u) = F(z)/2$ with $z = e^{iu}$, 
$F(z) =\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^{2^n}}{2^n}$, then 
           $ z F'(z) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}$ is a commonly-used example of a [lacunary function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function).

Comment: thank you for the reply! But I don't see how the fact that $zF'(z)$ is a lacunary function impy that $S$ cannot be wrote in terms of standard function. Lacunary means (from what I have understood) that it is not possible to provide analytic continuations outside it's radius of convergence. Since $S$ converges for every $u$, $F$ converges on the whole circunference $|z| = 1$,right? In short I'll be grateful if you could expand a little bit your answer :-)

Comment: The point is simply that $z F'(z)$ is a "known" function, which you'll see mentioned in many discussions of lacunary series, and many of its properties are known, but AFAIK nobody gives it a name.  Yes, $F(z)$ converges absolutely on $|z|=1$, but is not analytic at any point there.

Comment: I see.. What I don't understand is why the fact that $zF'(z)$ has that form (and is a lacunary function) imply that $F(z)$ cannot be expressed in terms of standard functions? :-)

Comment: If that function had a known expression in terms of standard functions, somebody would have mentioned that when discussing it.  Also, nearly all of the standard functions have analytic continuations to nearly all of the complex plane; very few have natural boundaries (Jacobi theta functions being notable exceptions)